# android: Problem Installing app to Emulator

Tags: android, installation

I want to install busybox to my emulator. I followed the following steps :
Start emulator from dos prompt
1) emulator –avd youravdname –partition-size 128

2) Copy file to /data/local
cat busybox > /data/local/busybox  OR
adb push busybox /data/local/busybox

3) STart shesll
adb shell

3) Mount as RW
su -c mount -o remount,rw /dev/block/mtdblock0 /system

4) Copy file to system 
cat /data/local/busybox > /system/xbin/busybox

5) Install busybox
cd /system/xbin
busybox --install .

Till step 4 all works perfectly fine. At Step 5, I get "No such fiel or directory" for each file that had to be installed. Like :

```
# busybox --install .
busybox --install .
busybox: /data/busybox/[: No such file or directory
busybox: /data/busybox/[[: No such file or directory
busybox: /data/busybox/addgroup: No such file or directory
busybox: /data/busybox/adduser: No such file or directory
busybox: /data/busybox/adjtimex: No such file or directory
busybox: /data/busybox/ar: No such file or directory
busybox: /data/busybox/arp: No such file or directory
busybox: /data/busybox/arping: No such file or directory
```

List goes on till file "zcip". I tried to install in /data/busybox folder also. There also I get the same. If I create a folder /busybox and the ntry to install, then I ger "Invalid device cross-link ..." for each file.

Can anyone help me know why is htis error and how to solve it. I got to have busybox installed. After doing lots of research I found the above steps that helped me gain some success till coping to /xbin. Now installing is the issue.

Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: Where did you download BusyBox from? Was it specifically an Android version? It could also be a permissions issue - did you run `busybox --install` as root? Finally, the `Invalid device cross-link` error is probably due to the BusyBox install script using Unix hard-links, which can only work within a single filesystem - /busybox, /data, and /system will all be on different filesystems so hard links will not work.

Comment: I don't rememebr from where I downloaded Busybox. But yes it was meant for Android and its version was 1.15... I am mounted to system with rw permission, so I guess I am root. "id" cmd says uid=0, so I am the root. With "busybox --install . , /data, /system, ./busybox all gives me "No such file or dir . With "ln -s busybox cp", I got the cp installed in /system/xbin as cp->busybox . Where am I going wrong ?

Comment: I finally succeeded installing busybx on the emulator. But it gets erased on shut down. Does this mean that every time I restart the emulator I got to perform steps to install it first. That's not a good idea. 

What do you guys say ??? Why does this happen and then how to handle this with real devices ??

Comment: With real devices, you can just install it from the market, and as with any other app from the market, it should stay installed. I get my BusyBox via SuperUser so I'm not sure of this, but you could try adding an emulated SD card to the emulator image, and moving/installing BusyBox to the SD card.

Comment: Thanks RivieraKid, will try installing on sdcard and see if it remains stable or that also gets erased.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried by copying busybox file to /sbin directory. I assume you know how to mount / partition in read-write mode (else run `mount -o rw,remount rootfs /`)

Then run:

```
mkdir /bin
mkdir /usr/bin
mkdir /usr/sbin
/sbin/busybox --install
```

It has worked for me!!

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to do more what you need to do.

Just use the following command to install an external apk in your emulator

```
adb install your_apk.apk
```

Help Link

http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/adb.html#move

Comment: My be this two links can help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4368127/is-it-possible-to-gain-root-and-or-install-busybox-on-the-android-emulator   and  http://benno.id.au/blog/2007/11/14/android-busybox  ..